# Check if a number exists with a range in DB

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find an efficient way to find out a if a number range provided by the user is already present in the ranges available in DB. There are two columns in the numbers table in DB which are  : **Starting Number** and **Ending Number**

Say a range exists where the Starting Number is : 102 and Ending number is 122 then the Starting of the next range would be : 123 or can be anywhere between 1 to 101

For Example the two Range table columns values are as below :

**Starting Number  | Ending Number**

[image]

So  if a user tries to create a new range say from : **190 to 220** or **85 to 105** he should get an error since the digits in this range already exists in the ranges in the DB.

So as per my example above, the user should always be allowed to create a range anything beyond **1700** say **1701** to **1750** or anything from missing ranges say from **251 to 299** or from **1251 to 1299**.

I was able to solve most of the scenarios using this query below but one scenario i couldnt get to work :

//For in between ranges which are available (Returns no value : works correctly)

```
select * from range
where 121  BETWEEN StartingNumber and EndingNumber
or 149  BETWEEN   StartingNumber and EndingNumber;
```

//For outer ranges (Returns no value : works correctly)

```
select * from range
where 1701  BETWEEN StartingNumber and EndingNumber
or 1800  BETWEEN   StartingNumber and EndingNumber;
```

//For overlapping range (Returns rows, so this range cant be created  : works correctly)

```
select * from range
where 150  BETWEEN StartingNumber and EndingNumber
or 160  BETWEEN   StartingNumber and EndingNumber;
```

**//But for a range say 690 to 1800 it fails as it returns no value but ranges beyond 700 till 1700 are already taken**

```
select * from range
where 690  BETWEEN StartingNumber and EndingNumber
or 1800  BETWEEN   StartingNumber and EndingNumber;
```

Is there a way i can get this last condition working as well?

Comment: use a DB tag, did you mean a database using SQL ?

Comment: Those things are usually done directly in the database, not in your java code.

Comment: if its db and sql you could issue a sql statement for `select * from <table> where newRangeStart <= startingNumber and newEndingNumber <=ending number` . if this returns anything range exists.

Comment: @MukulGoel: Counter example: newRangeStart=1, newEndingNumber=2, all values in DB > 2

Comment: Ah thanks for your reply Chris and Mukul . Yes its a SQL db so that is true ..I can do this using a query itself !

Comment: @ScottHunter how is that?. your example wont return anything and therefore the range does not exist?

Comment: @MukulGoel: Every record in my scenario satisfies your query.

Comment: To avoid confusion, please use the correct terms at the correct place. In a database we have tables, and inside tables we have columns. Saying "In database we have two columns" can lead to confusion.

Comment: @MukulGoel I tried your query on the DB but it  seems to return a value when the highest **Starting Number** in the DB Range table is 9000 and highest **Ending Number** is 9100 so now when i run the query with values                                                                             `select * from range
  where StartingNumber <= 15000
   and EndingNumber <= 15500`
This always returns a whole set of data .  Also it doesn't seem to work for in between ranges . I have a range from 1 - 8 and 15 to 20 and now if i tried to run a query with SN= 9 and EN= 14 it returns the values.

Comment: @MukulGoel I have updated my post please check the queries  i have tried . unfortunately I still struggling to solve the last scenario

Comment: @Joe; Try scotts answer below; seems to be covering all possible cases. Just prepare them as 3 separate sql statements and if anyone comes back with result then your range exists. you can also build up a compound sql statement with all the three clauses separated by an OR. this is better option

Comment: @MukulGoel I was able to solve it in a different way . I m putting the query below : I was able to solve this using this query below, it takes care of all the four scenarios mentioned above.:

     `SELECT count(StartingNumber) FROM range
      WHERE 690  BETWEEN   StartingNumber and EndingNumber
        or 1800  BETWEEN   StartingNumber and EndingNumber
        or StartingNumber in ( SELECT StartingNumber
              FROM range
              WHERE StartingNumber BETWEEN 690 AND 1800);`

Comment: @JoeRodreques      'SELECT * FROM range where 690 < StartingNumber and 1800 > EndingNumber'

Use this query in place of your last query.

Comment: @FarhanQasim that also gives me the same results as the query i have posted above. I can use either of them .. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this using this query below, it takes care of all the four scenarios mentioned above.:

```
  SELECT count(StartingNumber) FROM range
  WHERE 690  BETWEEN   StartingNumber and EndingNumber
    or 1800  BETWEEN   StartingNumber and EndingNumber
    or StartingNumber in ( SELECT StartingNumber
                            FROM range
                            WHERE StartingNumber BETWEEN 690 AND 1800);
```

Answer (score 1):

Proposed new range A..B isn't available if any of the following are true (which can be testing in a SQL query):

- There is a DB record where SN<=A and EN=>A *(an existing range covers at least the low end of proposed one)*
- There is a DB record where SN<=B and EN>=B *(an existing range covers at least the high end of proposed one)*
- There is a DB record where SN<=A and B<=EN *(an existing range is within proposed one)*

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to fetch all the rows to find a range. Just four queries according to the conditions on your question.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name_here WHERE 'InputStartingNumber' <= starting_number_column AND 'InputEndingNumber' >= ending_number_column;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name_here WHERE 'InputStartingNumber' <= ending_number_column AND 'InputEndingNumber' >= ending_number_column;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name_here WHERE 'InputStartingNumber' <= starting_number_column AND ending_number_column <= 'InputEndingNumber';

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name_here WHERE 'InputStartingNumber' >= starting_number_column AND 'InputEndingNumber'<= ending_number_column;
```

If any of these queries returns a count greater than 0, then it means that the range exists and your code should not allow the inputs to be stored in the DB.