# Finding Gaps in number Ranges in DB

Tags: mysql, sql

I had posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49860044/check-if-a-number-exists-with-a-range-in-db) previously on how i can find if number(s) exist in between a number range. I was able to resolve it using the query below

```
  SELECT count(StartingNumber) FROM range
  WHERE 690  BETWEEN   StartingNumber and EndingNumber
    or 1800  BETWEEN   StartingNumber and EndingNumber
    or StartingNumber in ( SELECT StartingNumber
                            FROM range
                            WHERE StartingNumber BETWEEN 690 AND 1800);
```

Now i am just wondering if would be possible to find the gaps in the various number ranges:

So, if there is a range from **1 - 100 , 101 - 135, 150 - 200, 201 - 255, 255 - 270, 301 - 326**

I want to find out the missing ranges **136 - 149, 217 - 300** etc.
Also an pictorial representation of DB  table columns is shown below :

[image]

Now I m trying to find out if would be possible to write an SQL query that will list the missing ranges **251 - 299**, **1251 - 1299**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select *
from
(
  select d1.hi + 1 tlo, min(d2.lo) - 1 thi
  from data d1
  join data d2 on d1.hi < d2.lo
  group by d1.hi
) t
where tlo < thi
```

[dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=7067d5f426ca1f745ca256627937386f)

The subquery finds the ranges between `hi` and `lo` and the outer query just select the correct ranges.

Comment: Thank you very much thats exactly what i was trying to achive!! Have a great day!!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use `subquery` with `?` cols that could specify your actual data ordering

```
select * from (
    select *, (select idto 
               from table 
               where ? < t.? 
               order by ? desc LIMIT 1)+1 as MissingFrm,
           idfrm-1 as MissingTo
     from table t
)tt where idfrm <> MissingFrm;
```